# How to increase graphics memory in OS X running as a client in VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, graphics, virtualization, virtualbox

How to increase graphics memory in OS X running as a client in VirtualBox? I installed OS X in VirtualBox and I have 4 GB graphics but it is showing the graphics display as 3 MB. How can I increase the graphics available?

Comment: Can you add some more details about your setup, especially the hardware you are running on and the OS X version you are using?

Comment: Hello i am using MAC OS X 10.8.3 (64 bit) in my WINDOWS 8 (64 bit) and My PC ram is 4 GB virtual box ram is 1796 MB in PC i have 4 GB graphic card but in mac it showing that (graphics display as 3 MB) My display video memory in Virtual box is 256 MB

Comment: PLZ BRO HELP ME :)

Comment: Running 10.8 on non-Apple hardware (even virtualized) is in conflict with the [license agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX108.pdf).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using OS X on non-Apple hardware.